# Using CURL in PHP to post text data starting with "@"

Tags: php, curl

I use CURL to post data in PHP like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```

where $args - array of parameters.

The problem is that one of the parameters has its value starting with "@". And according to CURL documentation, that means that I'm going to send a file. Which is not true in my case.
As a result I get the following error message: failed creating formpost data.

Is there a way to specify whenever I want to send a file or "@" is just a regular character that is part of some value?

Thanks,
Gena

Comment: Can I see an example of what would throw an error?

Comment: Next to the missing error message (please add it), you must not use an array but can also use a string. Please try as well with the string variant and tell if this also produces the same error.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that talks about that?

Comment: @MrD  
$postData = array();  
$postData['key'] = "@value";

Comment: @Waleed
Documentation: http://php.net/curl_setopt
Good thread about this issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50060

Comment: @hakra I've added the error message: failed creating formpost data. Do you mean any other error message? I know about the string option, but I cannot use it for other reasons :)

Comment: @Gena How about escaping the character? and then adding it in on the other side or replacing it with as ASCII code? Note the most elegant but it would get the job done?

Comment: @Gena: You *can* use the string option. Please do it and let us know if you still have the problem. Also PHP error messages come as a whole line telling the line of code etc., it's good to know whether this is a Warning, an Error etc. (the name/path of the file is not needed just place ... for that, line of code is interesting)

Comment: @MrD Tried. Working. Would like to find a better way :)

Comment: @hakra: I've tried strings - it works. Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the entire error message as I'm new to PHP.

Comment: Guys, thanks for help so far. I'd appreciate a way using arrays and not strings. Please note, that the error I get is by design and is documented. So we don't have actual problem with the error itself. We just need to know how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use percent encoding instead?  That way your '@' symbols would be %40 and CURL won't mess with them.  We usually percent encode all our post fields.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Starting with PHP 5.5, you can set the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to prevent the file upload behavior for strings starting with "@". For example.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
```

The default value is false for PHP 5.5.0 and true starting with 5.6.0

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php